# Framer Motion - How do I repeat an animation without the initial part?

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations, framer-motion

I'd like to animate an element in a very specific way using Framer Motion on my React project. It should go up from the bottom of the page when the animation first starts, but, once it hits about middle, it should just keep floating in place indefinitely - without ever going back to its initial position.

I'm fairly new to Framer Motion and couldn't find a solution. I've tried keyframes as well, but at some point the animation has to end and repeat from the beginning. What can I do to create this kind of behavior? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delay the second animation by the duration of the first animation. That way the second animation will seamlessly fire up as soon as the first bit ends considering there aren't any events involved. For example, if the duration of the first animation is 5 seconds, delay the second animation by 5 seconds.

As for implementing this using `framer-motion`, you can use the `motion` and the `initial` and `animate` props for the first animation and the `useAnimate` hook for the second animation. You can find all the steps for implementation in the `framer-motion` [docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/).

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. Other solution I found was simply animating two components. A div surrounding the element with the first animation and the element itself with the second, delayed. But the useAnimate path is definitely better. Thanks.

Comment: That’s great! Glad I could be of help.